# Как уже после получения числа сообщить программе в какой системе счисления оно находится? C++

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю задание из книги Страуструпа. Определить для себя систему счисления кое-как получается по префиксам, но как сообщить это программе и потом переводить в то что нужно?

Comment: Ну, если лень самому смотреть, с чего число начинается — то посмотрите на функцию [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) и как она работает, если основание указать как равное 0: *If the value of base is ​0​, the numeric base is auto-detected: if the prefix is 0, the base is octal, if the prefix is 0x or 0X, the base is hexadecimal, otherwise the base is decimal.*

Comment: Что значит лень самому смотреть, с чего число начинается?

Comment: Так и сообщить - если начинается с 0х, значит шестнадцатиричное. И т.д.

Comment: Это невозможно, если вы сами не запомнили в какой системе счисления число **было изображено символами**. После преобразования  все числа представлены в [одном формате](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::string s;
    int ans;
    std::cin >> s;
    if (s.size() > 1 && s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x')
        ans = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 16);
    else if (s.size() && s[0] == '0')
        ans = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 8);
    else
        ans = std::stoi(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Для `long long` используйте `std::stoll` вместо `std::stoi`.

Comment: Зачем просто, если можно сложно? :) Кстати, вы уж или везде `std::` добавляйте, или `using namespace std;` допишите, а то некомпилируемый код получается...

Comment: Забыл только у string, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Вот уж воистину — зачем просто, если можно сложно?

Решение nyekitka можно смело заменить на

```
int main () {
    std::string s;
    int ans;
    std::cin >> s;
    ans = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 0);
```

[Убедитесь сами](https://ideone.com/pX0G9f)...

А вот для вывода строки в скобках — да, нужно смотреть, какие первые два символа.